# join same table from different databases SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am try join two tables of the same name, but on different DBs on each other like this:

```
SELECT DB2.DBO.DICTIONARY.ID AS ID,
    DB2.DBO.DICTIONARY.NAME AS NN,
    DB1.DBO.DICTIONARY.NAME AS N
FROM DB2.DBO.DICTIONARY
INNER JOIN DB1.DBO.DICTIONARY AS DICT
ON DB2.DBO.DICTIONARY.ID = DICT.ID
```

But I keep getting the error:

> The multi-part identifier "DB1.DBO.DICTIONARY.NAME" could not be
>   bound.

What I aim to do, is join them on `ID` but give the `NAME` columns different aliases. Because the data in `DB1.NAME` is different than in `DB2.NAME`.

Comment: Use DICT.NAME AS N instead of DB1.DBO.DICTIONARY.NAME AS N in the select as you have already used alias for Dictionary table from DB1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used an alias for the table `DB1.DBO.DICTIONARY`, so you can't reference to it with the same name any more. You have to reference to it using the alias `DICT` instead:

```
SELECT 
  DB2.DBO.DICTIONARY.ID AS ID,
  DB2.DBO.DICTIONARY.NAME AS NN,
  DICT.NAME AS N
FROM DB2.DBO.DICTIONARY 
INNER JOIN DB1.DBO.DICTIONARY AS DICT
ON DB2.DBO.DICTIONARY.ID = DICT.ID
```